making a android app that will fetch data from strava app. In the redirect URI, I'm giving my package name but it is not getting redirected to my app
I have created a Android application, In the application I have got the Client ID, Client Secret from here https://www.strava.com/settings/api. In the redirect URI I'm giving my app package but it is not redirected to the application.
here is my manifest file:-
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.StravaPrac"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.StravaPrac">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="careplix.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/token-exchange"
                    android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>`

I tried giving a different URL, there the redirect is working. I'm getting the client code, state everything but the when I give app package it doesn't work, It should redirect back to the app.
here is some code to catch the response:-
 if (response != null) {
                val tokenRequest = TokenRequest.Builder(response.request.configuration, clientId)
                    .setGrantType(GrantTypeValues.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                    .setCodeVerifier(response.request.codeVerifier)
                    .setAuthorizationCode(response.authorizationCode)
                    .setRedirectUri(redirectUri)
                    .setRefreshToken(clientRefreshToken)
                    .build()


You will have to change your scheme in the manifest to:
 <data
                android:host="careplix.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/token-exchange"
                android:scheme="careplix" />

The scheme cannot be https. you have to give your application a unique scheme like "careplix". this way when a browser attempts to go to carplix://careplix.com/token-exchange it will open your app. (unless you are trying to open your app to a website after authentications which doesnt seem to be the case here). the scheme is used to determine which app will be used to handle the url. "https" is only handled by web browsers.
Next make your authorization callback domain "carplix.com/token-exchange". This tells strava which domain it is allowed to redirect to in order to avoid exploitation.
Hope this helps
